# Use Ampscript to set the subject line using OR and AND

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a data extension that tells me if the status is bronze, silver or gold. I have another with a boolean that tells me if it’s active (0 or 1).

```
If status is bronze or silver or gold and active

(Set subject line 1)

Elseif 

If status is bronze or silver or gold and not active
(Set subject line 2)

Elseif 

If status is trial and active

(Set subject line 3)

Endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your conditions really are like the following, it is different when you comebine `(... or status =="gold") and @status == "active` or if you write `(... OR @status == "silver") or (status =="gold" and @status == "active )`

```
%%[

var @status, @booleanField, @subjectline
set @status = [status]
set @booleanField = [nameOfTheBooleanFieldInTheDataextension]

IF (@status == "bronze" OR @status == "silver" OR  @status =="gold") AND @booleanField == "active" THEN
    set @subjectline = "A"
ELSEIF (@status == "bronze" OR @status == "silver" OR  @status =="gold") AND @booleanField != "active" THEN
    set @subjectline = "B"
ELSEIF @status == "trial" and @booleanField == "active"
    set @subjectline = "C"
/* Best Practise would be to always include all possible conditions therefore the ELSE condition should be here */
ELSE
    set @subjectline = "D"
ENDIF

]%%

%%=v(@subjectline)=%%
```

More for subjectline can be found in this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267707/use-ampscript-to-change-the-subject-line-based-on-data-extension-value/267711#267711)

Comment: Thanks, this works.